# Load more data functionality in data table?

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I am using 1.9.1 datatable and implementing load more functionality with server side processing.

On ready i load the data table with 10 rows say, When i click load more then I need to fetch another 10 rows from server  and append it in existing data 
instead of fetching 20 rows back from server.

Here is mine server side code

```
function(){
       oTable=      $('#customerTable').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "iDisplayStart":0,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']],
                    "aoColumns": [
                    {"aTargets": [0],"sName":"customer.fullName", "mData": function(response){
                        return response.customer.fullName;
                    }, "bSortable": false},
                    {"aTargets": [1],"sName":"updatedDate", "mData": function(response){
                        var updateDate = response.updatedDt;
                        return updateDate;
                    }, "bSortable": true},

                    ]

                    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {


                            }
                        });
            }
```

What i tried :-

On click of load more(which is my custom button not provided by data table )  I fire ajaxserver call  and get another 10 rows to add the existing data. For this i tried to use [fnAddData](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) but it did not work.
To add data i tried `oTable.fnAddData(new_data_from_server,false);` but it does not display on UI. When i do `oTable.fnGetData()` I see 20 rows but on
UI it still displya 10 old rows.

How can i chieve load more functionality ?